# RSA Signature Weak Padding Attack

Tags: rsa, padding, known-plaintext-attack, forgery

Assume that we have a message $m$ of size $n$, and it is padded with two `01` bytes in front. Then  the signature $s$ is computed using a private key $ks$. Can we still use the Known Message Attack to create a signature for message $m^2$ or $pad||m||pad||m$ by multiplying the signature with itself? Or will the padding stop this despite being weak?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we note $|m|$ the number of bits in the bytestring coding the message $m$, the first padding considered is $m\mapsto \tilde m=257\cdot2^{|m|}+m$, and the signature is $m\mapsto\tilde S(m)=S(\tilde m)=\tilde m^d\bmod N$, where $S$ is the textbook/naked RSA signing $m\mapsto m^d\bmod N$. Notice that for any $m$ small enough that $m^2$ can be signed, we can derive $S(m^2)$ as $\big(S(m)\big)^2\bmod N$; and if $n^2$ is too big, we may still have $S(m^2\bmod N)=\big(S(m)\big)^2\bmod N$.

**NO**, we can not derive $\tilde S(m^2)$ as $\big(\tilde S(m)\big)^2\bmod N$. That equality holds if and only if $\tilde m^2\equiv\widetilde{m^2}\pmod N$. At least, when $m$ is small enough that $\widetilde{m^2}<N$ or some similar huge bound (not explicit in the statement), that simplifies to $\tilde m^2=\widetilde{m^2}$, and there is no $m$ matching that: notice that the square of an integer which two leftmost bytes after removing leading zeroes are `0101` has its two leftmost bytes after removing leading zeroes among {`0102`, `0103`, `0104`}. I conjecture, without proof, that above said bound, we can not efficiently come up with any solution without knowing the factorization of $N$.

But **NO**, the scheme is not secure. Even with the (unstated) constraint of messages of the same width, it is easy to come up with distinct messages $m_0, m_1, m_2, m_3$ such that $\widetilde{m_0}\cdot\widetilde{m_1}=\widetilde{m_2}\cdot\widetilde{m_3}$; and then we can derive $\tilde S(m_3)$ as $\Big(\tilde S(m_0)\cdot\tilde S(m_1)\cdot\big(\tilde S(m_2)\big)^{-1}\Big)\bmod N$, where the inverse is computed $\pmod N$.

---

More generally, linear padding schemes (such as the second one proposed) are weak in RSA, and subject to attacks. See Dan Boneh's [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/RSA-survey.pdf), section 4.1.

Even non-linear padding schemes may be quite weak; for example [(INCITS/)ISO/IEC 9796:1991](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS/ISO/IEC%209796-1991) (informally known as ISO/IEC 9796-1, and mostly described in section 11.35 of the [HAC](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)) was [trounced](http://www.jscoron.fr/publications/iso9796-1.pdf) in 1999, then [withdrawn](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=17658).

Using a padding scheme with a hash helps, but is not an insurance of security against such forgeries, even in combination with a linear padding scheme; for example ISO/IEC 9796-2:1997 was [shown](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/203) to have a vulnerability (not practically exploitable in any setup that I know of), even in its strengthened variant of 2002, now officialy designated as ISO/IEC 9796-2 scheme 1 and in wide use, that prescribes a hash of at least 160 bits. However I do not know of any attack (even theoretical) on the padding of RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 of [PKCS#1](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/pkcs/files/h11300-wp-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard.pdf).

---

Conclusion: when at all possible, and in any setup where an adversary could obtain the signature of chosen messages, use RSA signature schemes with provably secure padding based on [Full Domain Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Domain_Hash), like RSASSA-PSS of PKCS#1, or when message recovery is needed ISO/IEC 9796-2 schemes 2 or 3 (although I have never seen a complete formal proof of the later ISO/IEC 9796-2 schemes, I trust them enough).

Answer (score 2):

Considering the padding as an addition, padded message passed to sign is $m\cdot 2^{16}+0101$, $0101$ in hexadecimal, assuming padding is done on the lower bytes (for higher bytes the logic is just the same). Being $e$ the private exponent, and $m^2$ computed in the size of $m$,

$(m\cdot 2^{16}+0101)^e \pmod m$ is very different from $(m^2\cdot 2^{16}+0101)^e\pmod m$, and clearly $(m\cdot 2^{16}+0101)^{2e}\neq(m^2\cdot 2^{16}+0101)^e$.

Comment: When signing, the private exponent _d_ is used, not the public exponent _e_. Also, the definition of the padding is now clarified, and is not as in this answer (please excuse my first comment, which was wrong).